# Electron Pipeline with exits error code 126

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, azure-devops, electron-builder

i have a pipeline which needs to run the electron-builder, but it exits error 126

Using chown and chmod i was able to get a lot close but there are still some errors:
[image]

My pipeline :

```
"- script: |
npm install
sudo chmod 777 -R ./
sudo chmod 777 -R /home/vsts/work/1/s/
sudo chown 777 -R ./
sudo chown 777 -R /home/vsts/work/1/s/
sudo chown 777 -R /root
workingDirectory: Front-end
displayName: 'Front-end: npm install'

- task: AWSShellScript@1
inputs:
awsCredentials: 'AWS_Deployer_bmtools'
regionName: 'eu-central-1'
scriptType: 'inline'
inlineScript: 'npm run dist'
disableAutoCwd: true
workingDirectory: 'Front-end'
```

Comment: Is this a self hosted agent?

Comment: not it is not self hosted (added another screenshot)

Comment: Please include anything that *can* be copy-pasted as copy-pasted text in your question, instead of as a screenshot :) screenshots are not searchable, they can't be copied to test your code in my IDE, and they have a tendency to expire when the image hosting service no longer hosts the image, which breaks the question/answer using them :)

Comment: i got a bit further, but still not the right permissions, i dont see what im missing